# Build android project from command line

Tags: android, command-line, makefile

I would like to build and android project from command line on Linux. In the root directory of the project there are the following files and directories:

`AndroidManifest.xml  build.xml  default.properties  res/  src/`

Can you provide a sample `Makefile` how to build this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have 'ant' installed? Try `ant debug`

Answer (score 3):

The build.xml file is input to the Ant program, which will build your project.  Use "ant build"